Pandas read_csv not reading all entries in large data file
I have a large .out file with 100002 rows. I am working in VSCode 1.88.0 and have Python 3.12.2 installed. I'm only reading two columns of data in the file: "Time" and "Sum(cvBot)", but when I read the datafile using pandas many entries are in the data viewer are NaNs when they are not in my original file. (For example, NaNs until row 10000 consistently, a similar problem persists when I specify an index column). The example of the data as viewed in VSCode is below:
       Time         cvTop        cvBot      Sum(cvTop)   Sum(cvBot)     cvCh0        cvCh1         cTop        cRoot         cBot        cvRoot    Sum(cvRoot)  Sum(cvNEql) TLevel      cGWL        cRunOff   Sum(cRunOff)    (cv(i),    Sum(cv(i)), i=1,NObs)
        [T]        [M/L2/T]     [M/L2/T]      [M/L2]       [M/L2]       [M/L2]      [M/L2]        [M/L3]      [M/L3]        [M/L3]      [M/L2/T]      [M/L2]       [M/L2]              [M/L3]        [M/L2]      [M/L3]      [M/L2/T]      [M/L2]
        0.0010  0.00000E+00 -0.15405E-02  0.00000E+00 -0.15405E-05  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.29945E+03  0.00000E+00  0.15410E+04  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00       1  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.29385E+03  0.29385E+00 -0.54338E+04 -0.54338E+01 -0.16439E+05 -0.16439E+02 -0.64983E+04 -0.64983E+01
        0.0020  0.00000E+00  0.43077E-02  0.00000E+00  0.27673E-05  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.30023E+03  0.00000E+00  0.15410E+04  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00       2  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.29437E+03  0.58822E+00 -0.43086E+04 -0.97424E+01 -0.93670E+04 -0.25806E+02 -0.70594E+04 -0.13558E+02
        0.0030  0.00000E+00  0.43077E-02  0.00000E+00  0.70750E-05  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.30070E+03  0.00000E+00  0.15410E+04  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00       3  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.29460E+03  0.88282E+00 -0.37590E+04 -0.13501E+02 -0.70042E+04 -0.32811E+02 -0.68129E+04 -0.20371E+02

.
.
.
        2.8186  0.00000E+00 -0.71450E-02  0.00000E+00  0.43578E-03  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.21151E+07  0.00000E+00  0.15397E+04  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00     998  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.18807E+07  0.41397E+06 -0.24422E+04 -0.70533E+03  0.91943E+02 -0.62800E+02  0.25422E+02 -0.37256E+03
        2.8193  0.00000E+00 -0.71450E-02  0.00000E+00  0.43083E-03  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.21229E+07  0.00000E+00  0.15397E+04  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00     999  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.18877E+07  0.41528E+06 -0.24486E+04 -0.70702E+03  0.91960E+02 -0.62737E+02  0.25429E+02 -0.37255E+03
        2.8200  0.00000E+00 -0.71450E-02  0.00000E+00  0.42588E-03  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.21307E+07  0.00000E+00  0.15397E+04  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00    1000  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.18946E+07  0.41660E+06 -0.24551E+04 -0.70872E+03  0.91977E+02 -0.62673E+02  0.25435E+02 -0.37253E+03


Here is the link to the data file if anyone is interested: Data
The image of my VSCode dataviewer is here as I can't copy paste the output.
Dataout
My intention is to read the two columns of data so that I can plot a time series. The current code for reading and plotting the data is:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


# Load time series data from a file
file_path = r'C:\Program Files\Hydrus-1D\Examples\Direct\Attempt10\solute1_Copy.out'

data = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=["Time", "Sum(cvBot)"], index_col=False, skiprows=[1], sep = " ")

I've also used one of the columns ("TLevel") as an index column but the rows of data are recorded as NaNs until row 15370.
I've gone through pages talking about similar issues, such as Pandas read_csv not reading all rows in file and I could not get it to work. I'm not sure what the problem is but there are extra columns of data which may or may not have a label at the rightmost columns in my dataset, which could be a cause. Is there anyway for me to get pandas to read my data file correctly?

I guess that there is something wrong with your file. Try to substitute all data in your file with random data and import again. If this works, then you should check what's in your original file, if there's some break or a missing field

Thanks for answering. I'm really hoping it's not the case, but I'll give this a try.

Ok so I substituted my data in the file with random data and ran the script with it, and NaNs are showing up in the time and Sum(cvBot) entries. So it is a file issue. Doesn't seem like there's a break or missing field.

so you didn't have a problem with random data?

No, even the random data produces a similar problem.

Interesting. Would it be possible to supply the file? If it contains information that should not be shared, then fill everything with random data.

BTW, the reason that I am excluding problems with row count is because pd.read_csv takes all rows by default

Hi Tino, I've supplied the datafile in my post. Thanks for clarifying about the row count issue.

Your file needs a bit of cleaning. There are a lot of spaces at the beginning that mess up with the import. I even tried it in excel and I could see the problem there. I will work on a script that reads the file as text and parses it accordingly

There are 18 columns in the data, but the data itself consists of 25 numbers. Is this true?

Yes that's right. Not sure if this would help, but this data is an output from a Hydrus1D software model, I'm not sure what the columns between 18 and 25 represent to be honest, as the data I'm interested in is only in the first few columns.

Good enough, just wanted to double check with you before, I'll assign column number for these columns...

Seems like you have a nice answer already

The last of your header row contain this:
(cv(i),    Sum(cv(i)), i=1,NObs)

I'm not sure how many columns that represent. Is it 1 or 4 columns?
You also used space (" ") to separate the data columns. Some columns are separate by 1 space, other use 2 spaces. It's better to use \s+ instead.
df = pd.read_csv(
    "solute1_Copy.out",
    skiprows=2,                    # skip the first 2 rows
    header=None,                   # the data now have no header
    sep="\s+",                     # one or multiple spaces separate the columns
    usecols=[0, 3],                # use the columns at index 0 and 3
    names=["Time", "Sum(cvBot)"],  # manually assign a name to them
    skipfooter=1,                  # skip the last row
    engine="python"                # to avoid a warning
)


saved for later, great answer!

It took a while for me to get back but I tried your solution and it works. Thanks for writing this and explaining clearly!.

The only issue you have (IMHO) is that you have fixed length records and are attempting to treat them as if they were delimited records. Use read_fwf() to read the rows as the fixed length data they are.
import pandas

file_name = "solute1_Copy.out"
fwidths = [(0, 14), (54, 67)]
df = pandas.read_fwf(file_name, colspecs=fwidths, index_col=False, skiprows=[1], skipfooter=1, dtype=float)
print(df)

Giving you:
             Time    Sum(cvBot)
0          0.0010     -0.000002
1          0.0020      0.000003
2          0.0030      0.000007
3          0.0030      0.000007
4          0.0031      0.000007
...           ...           ...
99996   4013.0000 -55104.000000
99997   4014.0000 -55104.000000
99998   4015.0000 -55104.000000
99999   4016.0000 -55104.000000
100000  4017.0000 -55104.000000


Thank you, I took a while to try this solution because I ended using MATLAB to work around these problems. It works great for me!

Your file needs to be tidied up before pandas can read it properly. There's a lot of random and inconsistent use of whitespace so this just needs to be cleaned. The following code removes any leading and trailing whitespace, and converts inconsistent whitespace between columns into a single space:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import re
import io


# Load time series data from a file
file_path = r'C:\Program Files\Hydrus-1D\Examples\Direct\Attempt10\solute1_Copy.out'

with open(file_path) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    file_contents = '\n'.join(lines)

file_contents = re.sub(' +', ' ', file_contents)

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file_contents), usecols=["Time", "Sum(cvBot)"], index_col=False, skiprows=[1], sep = " ")

The cleaning step can be simplified into two lines if you want to keep it more concise:
with open(file_path) as f:
    file_contents = re.sub(' +', ' ',  '\n'.join([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]))

Note the io.StringIO() call, as this converts the string into a file like object that pandas uses to read from.
This should allow pandas to read the data in properly, but note that you may need to specify the types of the expected data depending on your use case.
